# Need help getting my python script to loop a video more than once when motion is detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python script that runs on my Rasberry pi, it uses VLC and a PIR motion sensor.

I would like it to loop a video called lop.mp4 until motion is detected, at which point it plays mot.mp4 ... once this video finishes it goes back to looping lop.mp4 until motion is detected.

Currently I have it workeing EXCEPT it plays mot.mp4 the first time it detects motion, but wont do it again after that. I need a bit of help ensuring it does it more than once.

```
import gpiozero
import vlc
import time
import threading

# create a button that uses GPIO4
pir_sensor = gpiozero.MotionSensor(4)

# create vlc instance
player = vlc.Instance()

# create media player
media_player = player.media_player_new()

def play_video(path):
    media = player.media_new(path)
    media_player.set_media(media)
    media_player.play()
    # wait a bit for the player to start, then set fullscreen
    time.sleep(0.1)
    media_player.set_fullscreen(False)

def play_default_video_loop():
    play_video('/home/pi/elf/lop.mp4')
    while True:
        if media_player.get_state() == vlc.State.Ended:
            play_video('/home/pi/elf/lop.mp4')
        time.sleep(0.1)

def on_motion():
    print("Motion detected!")
    play_video('/home/pi/elf/mot.mp4')
    while media_player.get_state() != vlc.State.Ended:
        time.sleep(0.1)  # wait for video to finish
    play_default_video_loop()  # restart default video loop

pir_sensor.when_motion = on_motion

# start playing default video in a new thread
threading.Thread(target=play_default_video_loop).start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting")

media_player.stop()
```

I need to lop.mp4 to loop when there is no motion and the mot.mp4 to play when there is motion, currently I can only get mot.mp4 to work on the first detection of motion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import gpiozero
import vlc
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
flag = 1
# create a button that uses GPIO4
pir_sensor = 4
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pir_sensor, GPIO.IN)
# create vlc instance
player = vlc.Instance()

# create media player
media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer(player)

def play_video(path):
    media_player.set_media(vlc.Media(path))
    media_player.play()


def on_motion():
    media_player.set_media(vlc.Media('/home/pi/elf/mot.mp4'))
    media_player.play()
    # global flag
    # flag=0
    while media_player.get_state() != vlc.State.Ended:
        time.sleep(0.0001)  # wait for video to finish
    # flag =1
   
p_input_flag = 0
def edge_detect(input_flag):
    global p_input_flag
    output = 0
    if(input_flag  and (not p_input_flag)):
        output = 1
    p_input_flag = input_flag
    return output
try:
    play_video('/home/pi/elf/lop.mp4')
    while True:
        # if flag:
        if(edge_detect(GPIO.input(pir_sensor) == True)):
            on_motion()
        if media_player.get_state() == vlc.State.Ended:
            play_video('/home/pi/elf/lop.mp4')  # restart default video loop
            
        time.sleep(0.0001)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting")

media_player.stop()
```